# Capturar imagenes y monstrarlas en respectivas ImageView?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un activity de registro en mi app , donde el usuario debe sacar 3 fotos 
1) de  Su perfeil
2- Parte frontal del documento
3)Parte dorsal del  documento...
 Solo llego a poublicar la primera imagen, que seria  la foto del perfil ,a las del documrnto , me publica cualquier imagen , menos de las que saque 
no se donde esta mi error 
ahi esta mi codigo

```
takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });
    dniFrente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakeFrenteIntent();                
        }
    });

    dniDorsal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {             
            dispatchTakeDorsalIntent();
        }
    });
}
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

private void dispatchTakeFrenteIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE2);
    }
}
private void dispatchTakeDorsalIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE3);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        imageTop.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        picFrente.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE3 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        picDorsal.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer , es para cada imagen capturado , se muetra en su ImageView respectiva
ya Gracias.

Comment: en los permisos de la aplicacion especificaste acceso a datos de usuario ?

Comment: Sii ya tengo puesto todos los permisos

Comment: cuales son los valores de REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE 1 2 y 3 ?  @ApseSony

Comment: los valores de REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE 1 2 y 3  son :20 ; 23 y 25